# how to change row height in FullCalendar?

Tags: css, laravel-5, fullcalendar, bootstrap-4

this is my controller

```
      $calendar = Calendar::addEvents($events)
      ->setOptions([ //set fullcalendar options
          'firstDay' => 1,
          'height' => '200px',
          'themeSystem' => 'bootstrap3',
          'columnHeader' => false,
          'aspectRatio' => 1

      ]);
```

I change the height of container but cell size remains with a scrolling bar

[i want to change my calendar like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5qJm.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replacing `height` with `contentHeight` should help change the size.

You might need more than 200px because it takes into account the whole calendars height rather than just one row. So if it was set to 1000, each section row would have a height of 162 or 329 if it was set to 2000.

So you'll just need to change:

```
'height' => '200px',
```

to

```
'contentHeight' => 1300,
```

You don't need to include the `px`.

Comment: Thank you SWC Actually, I need to change the height of section rows to have a smaller size calendar on my page. But after doing this change cell size remains same as before.

Comment: If you change the value of `contentHeight` to something lower then that should reduce the row height, and the calendar height overall.

Comment: Here's a basic [JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/LLb11agg/). Just change the `contentHeight` to see the change in row height.

Comment: I updated the question with a picture and it is the look what I want in the calendar

Comment: Try adding the following CSS: `.fc-basic-view .fc-body .fc-row { min-height: 1em; }`. This will need adding after the calendars stylesheet / replacing in the stylesheet because it is overwriting the default.

Comment: can you please also suggest a way to color the cell for events?

Comment: You can change the color of the current day using: `.fc-unthemed td.fc-today { background: blue; }` and change the color for specific dates using `.fc-unthemed td.fc-widget-content[data-date="2017-12-07"] { background-color: green; }`. You just need to change the date to whatever you need in the same format.

Comment: I added the above css code to the same place where I added the css code to change the height. but neither today date or event date color changed.

Comment: neither height nor content height makes any difference to the row height. you just get more to scroll